# Flask неправильно воспринимает вопросительный знак (?) в route

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Столкнулся со странной ошибкой Flask при написании route.
Код программы:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/xmlhttprequest?account-id=<int:id>')
def main(id):
    if id == 1:
        return 'account john'
    else:
        return 'account not found'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Мы видим, что в route прописан вопросительный знак, перейдя по ссылке http://127.0.0.1:5000:5000/xmlhttprequest?account-id=1, получаем ошибку `Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Убрав в route вопросительный знак, (`@app.route('/xmlhttprequestaccount-id=<int:id>')`), оставив остальную часть программы в том же состоянии, перейдя по ссылке http://127.0.0.1:5000:5000/xmlhttprequestaccount-id=1, получим желаемый ответ `account john`.
Подскажите, как нужно действовать правильно.

Comment: После `?` в URL - это передача параметров. У сервера не может быть пути содержащего вопросительный знак. Так что путь должен быть `/xmlhttprequest`, а дальше копайте в сторону `request` на тему как достать параметры (ваш `account-id`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения Flask, все что идет после вопросительного знака - это не часть пути, а параметры запроса. Нужно получать переданный `account-id` из [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args):

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/xmlhttprequest')
def main():
    account_id = request.args.get('account-id', type=int)
    if account_id == 1:
        return 'account john'
    else:
        return 'account not found'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Хотя и догадывался, что такое существует, но не смотрел в документацию, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы сделали - не совсем правильно. Как вариант вы можете использовать: `Flask URL Converters`

Для этого измените ваш роутер:

```
@app.route('/xmlhttprequest/<int:id>')
```

И далее обращайтесь к нему по:

http://127.0.0.1:5000:5000/xmlhttprequest/1

Comment: Ну это как вариант костыля сойдет, спасибо за ответ все равно.

Comment: Вариант который выше указан - больше подходит под вашу задачу, согласен.